# Windows XP error message: "Windows cannot find 'explorer.exe'"

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

In Windows XP I can open `"My Computer"` and see all the hard drives. I can also see the `explorer.exe` process running among other processes in Task Manager. But after opening "My Computer", when I double click on one of the drives to open it, I get the following error message:

> Windows cannot find 'explorer.exe'. Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly, and then try again. To search for a file, click the start
>   button, and then click search.

Although I could detect and remove several suspicious files using `Malwarebytes` & `Microsoft Security Essentials`, the problem still remains. The interesting point is that if I right click on one folder and select `Open` or `Explore` from the menu bar, I can open the folder! but if I double click on the folder, it does not open and I get the above error message. How can I fix this problem? Any advice would be appreciated!

**Update:** I formatted the C: drive (NTFS), a deep format, and installed a fresh Windows XP on it. I am not getting this error when I double click on C drive icon anymore. But the same error appears when I double click on other drive names. Maybe I should format them too!

Comment: My guess: you have still got some malware, which has intercepted the double-click action, but is broken. Or the hook is still there and the malware it refers to is not.

Comment: or explorer.exe itself has been patched/injected by the malware, you are best to do a Clean Install of XP.